# Hyperlink to a file using the current user

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, office365, hyperlink, sharepoint

I am trying to create a hyperlink which will work for everyone on different machines.

For example, this works for me:

```
C:\Users\bob\text.txt
```

However, will not work for users on a computer who do not have a user account named bob.

Is there a way to replace the username with the current logged in user? For example:

```
C:\Users\{current_user}\test.txt
```

I found `%USERPROFILE%` but this does not work.

A bit of background info. Everyone has access to our SharePoint 365, however, in procedures, I would like to be able to hyperlink to folders in the SharePoint that they already have access to which would then open the file or file explorer. At the moment, we are having to create a share link, which then opens the file in a browser which isn't optimum.

Thank you

Comment: Why does that not work? Since it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Seth I am creating these hyperlinks in MS Word (as this is where they are going to be used). If I run from CMD, they work as expected. If I export as a PDF, I can see that Word has amended the hyperlink to %25USERNAME%25. Same goes for %USERPROFILE%.

Comment: %25 is a different encoding for %. Maybe try to figure out whenever you can suppress that conversion.

Comment: Turns out that environment variables are not supported when using file:/// (which is what MS Office applications use to create hyperlinks)...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering), any problem can be solved by introducing an extra level of indirection. Let's see how we can make a Microsoft Office hyperlink take us to something else that *does* support environment variables.

1. Create a batch file containing this:

   `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %userprofile%\test.txt`
2. Save it somewhere on the network that all of your users can access. Let's say you've saved it as `N:\OpenProfile.bat`.
3. Make the hyperlink point to `N:\\OpenProfile.bat` or `file:///N://OpenProfile.bat`.

(Admittedly, this doesn't scale well, as you'll need a separate batch file for each target file.)

Comment: Good idea, however, as you said, it doesn't scale well. We probably have around 100 hyperlinks across as many documents. Know of any other way I can open file explorer to the correct directory? Thanks Doug.

Comment: My first thought is to have a single batch file that takes an argument for the particular file to be opened. As long as all of the files are within `%userprofle%`, that might work. But I haven't had time to experiment with that yet.